# Open a word document file in web based ms office using Angular application

Tags: angular, web, browser, office365, angular8

I want to open a word document file in web based ms office ( office 365 ) from the Angular application.
So, for example

1. I have  running angular application
2. A word document is received from backend (node js ) by calling a get url.
3. Once the document file is received, I want to make the Angular application open it on the browser in ms office ( web view ).

Is it possible first of all? And yes then is there any API or how will the things to be carried after 3rd Step above.

Note: The user using Angular application is already logged in office 365 on the browser.